# In R, how to delete a series of cells based on the value from another cell?

Tags: r, loops, iteration, tidyverse, rowdeleting

I have a 300x300 df. Each row represents the data of a different patient, named with an id. The first 2 columns are the patients id´s. Column 'id_all' contains more participants than needed, and than 'id'. My goal is to keep only the patient information that corresponds with the first column, 'id'.

The first 9x9 looks like this:

| id | id_all | MMSE BL | MMSE 12 | MMSE 24 | MMSE 36 | MMSE 48 | MMSE 60 | MMSE 72 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa002 | aaa000 | 22 | 18 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| aaa003 | aaa002 | 29 | 28 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 29 | NA |
| aaa005 | aaa003 | 30 | 29 | 30 | 30 | 30 | NA | NA |
| aaa024 | aaa005 | 29 | 28 | 25 | NA | NA | 25 | NA |
| aaa026 | aaa024 | 30 | 29 | 29 | 29 | NA | NA | NA |
| aaa048 | aaa026 | 28 | 30 | 28 | 27 | 30 | 30 | NA |
| aaa095 | aaa038 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 26 | NA | NA | NA |
| aaa222 | aaa048 | 30 | 29 | 29 | 28 | 28 | 29 | NA |

So, based on the first column, I would like to somehow iterate through the second column, **and delete all the information of the participants who do not have a match with the first column, 'id'.** This means, in the first row, deleting columns 2:300, and keeping the first column intact.

At the end, I want my df to look like this:

| id | id_all | MMSE BL | MMSE 12 | MMSE 24 | MMSE 36 | MMSE 48 | MMSE 60 | MMSE 72 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa002 | aaa002 | 29 | 28 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 29 | NA |
| aaa003 | aaa003 | 30 | 29 | 30 | 30 | 30 | NA | NA |
| aaa005 | aaa005 | 29 | 28 | 25 | NA | NA | 25 | NA |
| aaa024 | aaa024 | 30 | 29 | 29 | 29 | NA | NA | NA |
| aaa026 | aaa026 | 28 | 30 | 28 | 27 | 30 | 30 | NA |
| aaa048 | aaa048 | 30 | 29 | 29 | 28 | 28 | 29 | NA |
| aaa095 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| aaa222 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

In this example, id_all aaa000, and aaa038 dont have a match in the id column, so I would like the delete all the information about those participants.
I can´t figure it out how to delete almost all the row (almost because only the first two cells remain), and to move all the cells up.

Another possibility will be, to *move the first column down* until id matches id_all, and then delete the whole row that has an empty cell in the id column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will serve the purpose

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(!is.na(match(id_all, df$id))) %>% select(-id)

  id_all MMSE.BL MMSE.12 MMSE.24 MMSE.36 MMSE.48 MMSE.60 MMSE.72
1 aaa002      29      28      28      29      30      29      NA
2 aaa003      30      29      30      30      30      NA      NA
3 aaa005      29      28      25      NA      NA      25      NA
4 aaa024      30      29      29      29      NA      NA      NA
5 aaa026      28      30      28      27      30      30      NA
6 aaa048      30      29      29      28      28      29      NA
```

Since `id == id_all` in the final data, there is no need for a duplicate column.  If it is needed, it can be easily created by adding `mutate(id = id_all)` at the end of the above syntax

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(match(id_all, df$id))) %>% select(-id) %>% mutate(id = id_all) %>%
  select(id, everything())

      id id_all MMSE.BL MMSE.12 MMSE.24 MMSE.36 MMSE.48 MMSE.60 MMSE.72
1 aaa002 aaa002      29      28      28      29      30      29      NA
2 aaa003 aaa003      30      29      30      30      30      NA      NA
3 aaa005 aaa005      29      28      25      NA      NA      25      NA
4 aaa024 aaa024      30      29      29      29      NA      NA      NA
5 aaa026 aaa026      28      30      28      27      30      30      NA
6 aaa048 aaa048      30      29      29      28      28      29      NA
```

`dput` of `df` used

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("aaa002", "aaa003", "aaa005", "aaa024", 
"aaa026", "aaa048", "aaa095", "aaa222"), id_all = c("aaa000", 
"aaa002", "aaa003", "aaa005", "aaa024", "aaa026", "aaa038", "aaa048"
), MMSE.BL = c(22L, 29L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 30L), MMSE.12 = c(18L, 
28L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 29L, 29L), MMSE.24 = c(NA, 28L, 30L, 
25L, 29L, 28L, 29L, 29L), MMSE.36 = c(NA, 29L, 30L, NA, 29L, 
27L, 26L, 28L), MMSE.48 = c(NA, 30L, 30L, NA, NA, 30L, NA, 28L
), MMSE.60 = c(NA, 29L, NA, 25L, NA, 30L, NA, 29L), MMSE.72 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

> df
      id id_all MMSE.BL MMSE.12 MMSE.24 MMSE.36 MMSE.48 MMSE.60 MMSE.72
1 aaa002 aaa000      22      18      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2 aaa003 aaa002      29      28      28      29      30      29      NA
3 aaa005 aaa003      30      29      30      30      30      NA      NA
4 aaa024 aaa005      29      28      25      NA      NA      25      NA
5 aaa026 aaa024      30      29      29      29      NA      NA      NA
6 aaa048 aaa026      28      30      28      27      30      30      NA
7 aaa095 aaa038      29      29      29      26      NA      NA      NA
8 aaa222 aaa048      30      29      29      28      28      29      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

In tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(id == id_all)
```

In base:

```
df[df$id == df$id_all, ]
```